# Set static variable before creating objects C++

Tags: c++, class

Before creating object I need to set static int number to zero (0).

In main.cpp there is call to function `A::resetNumber()`

In a.h there is private: (`static int number`)
And inline function: `static void resetNumber() { number = 0; }`

But result:

```
/tmp/ccXtEOHO.o: In function `Treadmill::resetNumOfTreadmills()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9Treadmill20resetNumOfTreadmillsEv[_ZN9Treadmill20resetNumOfTreadmillsEv]+0x6): undefined reference to `Treadmill::numOfTreadmills'
/tmp/ccFNFppU.o: In function `Treadmill::Treadmill()':
treadmill.cpp:(.text+0x231): undefined reference to `Treadmill::numOfTreadmills'
treadmill.cpp:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `Treadmill::numOfTreadmills'
treadmill.cpp:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `Treadmill::numOfTreadmills'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: do you have the answer to your question? if so, choose one of the answers aboove for the future readers: they will know which one to look for when they face similar problems

Comment: After finishing some other problems I will post answer to this one, And will check if there is other unasnwered questions.

Comment: ok so vote for all the anwers that you found useful it will give tips to people in the meantime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

headers only define the definition of what a class has, you still need to allocate some storage for the members.

Normally, with non-static members, a call to new (or an alloc on the stack) will create this storage. As statics are 'global' to all instances, you can't allocate them in this way, so you must define some storage manually - in a source file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the static variable in a source file. Example:

In header:

```
#pragma once
static int number; // only a declaration!
void resetNumber() { number = 0; }
```

In source:

```
int number = 0; // definition!
```

**Another approach:**

Sometimes this may also be an option:

```
inline int& AccessStaticNumber() {
    static int number = 0;
    return number;
}
```

This approach requires only a header. You can use it for example like this:

```
AccessStaticNumber() = 0;
int q = 3*AccessStaticNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simpler

in header file

```
class A
{
public:
  static int a;
  static void setA(int a);
  static void resetA();
};
```

in cpp file

```
int A::a=0;

void A::setA(int a)
{
    this->a=a;
}


void A::resetA()
{
    a=0;
 }
```

to use this variable you only need to call it with `A::a;`

this initialization occurs before the main happens

You can also change the value of a via

```
A::resetA();
```

Comment: Yes, But I need that reset function. I can't change main.cpp